# Problem downloading images via landsatxplore.api

Tags: python, landsat, landsat-8, download, landsatxplore

I use landsatxplore python package to download some landsat images. I have used it to download images taken one year before and it worked. I have written some Python code to download the images via a loop. When I try to download some recent images (i.e. in the current month - March in 2024), I got the following error:

Download failed with dataset id 1 of 2. Re-trying with the next one.
None of the archived ids succeeded! Update necessary!

Have I missed anything?

I have attached my code.

```
import time
from landsatxplore.api import API
from landsatxplore.earthexplorer import EarthExplorer

username= 'xxxxx'
password= 'xxxxx'

api = API(username, password)
ee = EarthExplorer(username, password)

scenes = api.search(
    dataset='landsat_ot_c2_l1',
    latitude=50.85,
    longitude=-4.35,
    start_date='2024-03-01',
    end_date='2024-03-25',
    # max_cloud_cover=10,
)

print(f"{len(scenes)} scenes found.")

max_retries = 3  # Maximum number of download retries

for scene in scenes[:2]:
    landsat_product_id = scene['landsat_product_id']
    landsat_scene_id = scene['landsat_scene_id']
    
    print(f"Downloading {landsat_product_id} - {landsat_scene_id}")
    
    retries = 0
    while retries < max_retries:
        try:
            ee.download(landsat_scene_id, output_dir='new_attempt')
            print("Download completed successfully!")
            break  # Break out of the retry loop if download is successful
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error downloading {landsat_product_id} - {landsat_scene_id}: {e}")
            retries += 1
            if retries < max_retries:
                print(f"Retrying... (Attempt {retries})")
                time.sleep(5)  # Add a delay before retrying to avoid overloading the server
            else:
                print("Max retries reached. Skipping this scene.")
    
print("Downloads for the first two scenes completed.")
```